# How download file from IPFS using public key or private key

Tags: blockchain, ipfs

How can I restrict people to download file from IPFS? People will download if I allow them using there public/private key.

Answer (score 1):

To restrict the people allowed to upload files to IPFS you have two solutions. In both cases, if your files are encrypted, you must have keys to decrypt them.

The first is the restriction using another port on your IPFS node. 
You put some other nodes of your network in the bootstrap list. 
You can then monitor with the order 
`ipfs swarm peers`

The other solution is the creation of a private network accessible only by certain nodes. I leave you a link that allows you to see how to do it: https://medium.com/@mycoralhealth/learn-to-securely-share-files-on-the-blockchain-with-ipfs-219ee47df54c

You can also upload an encrypted file and provide your key to the recipient to decrypt it. This way a person will not be able to do anything with the file without the key.

I hope I could have helped you.